# How does a PaymentGateway signal a completed order

Tags: 8, commerce

I'm trying to implement the Commerce Ingenico payment gateway for a Drupal 8 Commerce site. As this module is still in unfinished for Drupal 8, I'm fixing it up as I go. Most of the implementation is located in Composer packages, so it's mostly plumbing.

I'm hitting a bit of a wall now though. I'm using the off-site payment gateway, and I've configured the IPN (server to server notification). The values for the payment in the database look good*, but the Cart never turns into an Order. Somehow the trigger for signaling a completed payment to the order is missing.

The results is that after returning from the offsite payment (and the onNotify has already been triggered, so the payment is marked as completed), I end up back at the start of the payment flow; the order summary.

How are these parts supposed to fit together?

Here's the code to the onNotify method in the PaymentGateway:

```
public function onNotify(Request $request) {
    parent::onNotify($request);

    // Common response processing for both redirect back and async notification.
    $payment = $this->processFeedback($request);

    // Let's also update payment state here - it's safer doing it from received
    // asynchronous notification rather than from the redirect back from the
    // off-site redirect.
    $state = $request->query->get('STATUS') == PaymentResponse::STATUS_AUTHORISED ? 'authorization' : 'completed';
    $payment->setState($state);
    $payment->setAuthorizedTime(REQUEST_TIME);
    if ($request->query->get('STATUS') != PaymentResponse::STATUS_AUTHORISED) {
      // setCapturedTime has been relegated to the mists of history
      $payment->setCompletedTime(REQUEST_TIME);
      // $payment->setCapturedTime(REQUEST_TIME);
    }
    $payment->save();
  }
```

And this is the resultant row in the commerce_payment table:

```
 payment_id
13

type
payment_default

uuid
payment_default

payment_gateway
ogone_offsite

payment_gateway_mode
test

payment_method
NULL

order_id
29

remote_id
3039111240

remote_state
9

amount__number
26.400000

amount__currency_code
EUR

refunded_amount__number
0.000000

refunded_amount__currency_code
EUR

state
completed

authorized
1534516744

expires
0

completed
1534516744

test
NULL

captured
NULL
```

- Of course I don't know what these values are supposed to look like. I'm actually a little concerned about payment_method being NULL in this row. Is that normal for an offsite payment gateway, or should that be set to something?

Comment: I haven't worked with commerce on drupal 8 but typically on drupal 7 there'd be a rule fired when the payment's made to check if it matched the order total and set the order status accordingly. Does that help at all?

Comment: Rules isn't even a dependency for the new version anymore. 

I think it's all in the code now, and if I'm really unlucky obfuscated through lots of DI and services.

Comment: I was never a fan of the Rules integration but it did mean some of the most critical logic could be tweaked without coding. Seems like a step back if that's not accessible any more.

Comment: You might be looking for EventSubscribers/TransitionStates.

Comment: Try doing it exactly how the `OnReturn` method does it in [payment_example OffsiteRedirect.php](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce/tree/modules/payment_example/src/Plugin/Commerce/PaymentGateway/OffsiteRedirect.php?h=8.x-2.x#n73) which uses a `create` method.

Comment: @NoSssweat : that sounds like cargo cult programming. It should not be that hard to understand how a completed payment signals a completed order. 

Besides; a payment's already been created in a form extending Drupal\commerce_payment\PluginForm\PaymentOffsiteForm, I pass the payment id to my external url, get it returned to me on the onNotify, and complete that specific payment.

Comment: Just to clarify, your issue is that an order is not created or that an order is not updated after saving the payment?

Comment: I added clarification. A Cart is of course a draft order, so depending on your point of view there is or isn't an order. There is, however, definitely an object that implements  \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface .

Comment: Which Order workflow are you using? Have you tried other payment modules to see if they are working?

Comment: I've got to admit I have no idea which order workflow I'm using. The workflow seems like where I ought to be looking. Is there a page with an overview that shows how it's configured?

Comment: This seems to be a good start https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/orders/workflows

Comment: Far as I can tell from scattered logged messages my Payment uses the 'payment_default' workflow, and my order the 'order_default' workflow.


I'm currently considering just getting the order in my payment, and setting the State to 'completed'. I'm sure it's not best practices, but it might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar scenario has been discussed on #commerce Slack on Monday. In contrast to `onReturn()` no transition is triggered after `onNotify()`.

@bojanz says:

> it's a safeguard we'll need to add to Commerce, but won't have the resources to do so before october
>
> once we have $order->balance and an order paid in full event, we can use it to auto-place the order
>
> at least those two parts could land in september for 2.10

---

TL;DR

`onReturn()` must create a Payment, as suggested in a comment from @No Sssweat. In case `PaymentGatewayException` is thrown Commerce will redirect to the previous checkout step.
`onNotify()` can register info about payment but, at the current state, it won't **place** the order for you.

Comment: I have to continue using onNotify, as onReturn has proven to be unreliable; customers tend to close the tab after paying, and before returning. This is the exact scenario onNotify was created to avoid.

For the time being I manually trigger the transition after verifying payment success in onNotify. Would you say this is the best solution in the current state of things?

Comment: I must say no - too much logic in `onNotify()`. I understand the reasons why `onReturn()` is unreliable, I did experience it myself for some payment gateways. Nevertheless, I would leave `onNotify()` without an extra bit of code that does order transition, so once Commerce adds "order paid in full" event you'll be covered, and `onReturn()` will still do its job. In the same time I'll probably implement some custom safeguard, such as hook_cron to determine orders fully paid that haven't been * placed * and run the transition.

Comment: FYI In the past I also had issues with Payment providers that pushed notification only once, not logging failure or anything, and they even admitted that their delivery rate is quite poor. In addition there was no way to secure webhook endpoint on Drupal side because they were using random(ish) IPs, couldn't deliver hmac, token or anything. I ended up pulling status every time I got any request on webhook. 
I'm saying that just to highlight that one cannot always rely on `onNotify()` either.

Comment: This particular provider I can rely on: it will push multiple notifications if an error occurs, and the whole thing is signed with a private key. I'll contact the original developers and see if they want my fixes. If so I'll hook into cron for your suggested method.

Comment: I'm not sure why they haven't just used the transitions on the Payment object as well. Could the order then not just subscribe to payment transitions and reliably finish up orders? I'm sure there's a reason - there always is.